# How to disable break point in different file with same name in different module in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I have two different files in different modules but the same name, when I put debug point in one file, another file shows up when debugging and with the wrong line pointed on the debugger.

Comment: If that's happening consistently you might want to report it as a bug! https://issuetracker.google.com/components (I linked the main list so you can see the *Emulator* tracker says to file new bugs on the main *Android Studio* one)

Comment: yes, if always the case with Android Studio Bumblebee.

Comment: They're on Chipmunk now (*2021.2.1*) so maybe try updating and see if it's fixed - but that sounds like the kind of bug that might not get noticed since it's such a specific situation, so if it's not fixed in the current version it's worth letting them know

Comment: yes, here is the ticket created : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/243324838